# Foreach Loop With TWO or MORE Conditions

Tags: php, loops, foreach, simple-html-dom

Here is my original which works (I'm using simple-html-dom)

```
foreach(($filtered->find('a'))  as $element) {
// do stuff
}
```

Problem is that now I may need to use 2 conditions... something like:

```
foreach(($filtered->find('a'))  as $element || ($filtered->find('img'))  as $element) {
// do stuff
}
```

But it doesn't work. Neither does:

```
foreach(($filtered->find('a') || $filtered->find('img'))  as $element) {
// do stuff
}
```

How does one go about implementing both conditions so it runs the "do stuff" whenever EITHER an 'a' element OR an 'img' element is found.

Thank you very much for any help you can give.

Comment: have you tried using the simple_dom_html function to select more than one tag in your find? You can do a foreach($filtered->find('a, img') as $element) . For more information about what the library allows you to do you can check in the online documentation : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach(array_merge($filtered->find('a'),$filtered->find('img')) as $element) {
 // do stuff
}
```

`foreach` takes no conditions at all.

`foreach` takes *ALL* values from *ONE* array.

So if you want to take *ALL* values from *TWO* arrays, you have to merge *TWO* arrays into *ONE* array, and `foreach` over that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
foreach( $filtered->find('a, img') as $element ) { ... }
```

Using the comma, this will gets you all `a` and `img` nodes...

For more informations, please refer to [`PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `||` is a boolean operator and just returns `true` or `false`. If you want the first non-false value in a series of expressions, use `?:`:

```
foreach(($filtered->find('a') ?: $filtered->find('img'))  as $element) {
    // do stuff
}
```